# Does Chrome or Chromium tell you anywhere in the UI whether it's using v10 or v11 cookie encryption?

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, chromium

Chromium has two modes of storing cookies,

- v10: Uses static private key "peanuts" salted with "saltysalt"
- v11: Stores private key in Operating System's key chain

Does Chromium expose through the UI anywhere which one is used?